# Extending arrays in C using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I'm learning pointers in C. To get into details, I'm working on an array program. What I'm trying to achieve is, if the array is of size 0(initially) create a dynamic array using malloc of size 2 and then add the element in the initial position.

Furthermore, when more elements are added and if the total elements == size of the array, I create a new array using malloc with twice the previous size. I create a temporary array, copy elements from the previous array, then add the new element in the end. The problem is when I try to print the elements I get the address of the last element instead of the element.

Here's the full code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void display(int *arr, int *total_elements)
{
    if(*total_elements==0){
        printf("No elements present in array\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i< *total_elements;i++){
            printf("%d\t",*(arr+i));
        }
    }
}

void push(int *arr, int *size, int ele, int *total_elements)
{
    if(*size==0)
    {
        *arr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
        arr[*size] = ele;
        *total_elements = *total_elements + 1;
        *size = *size + 2;
        return;
    }
    else if(*size>*total_elements)
    {
        arr[*total_elements] = ele;
        *total_elements = *total_elements + 1;
        return;
    }
    else if(*size==*total_elements)
    {
        int *temp,i;
        temp = (int*)malloc((*(size)*2)*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0;i < *size;i++)
        {
            temp[i] = *(arr+i);
        }
        temp[i]=ele;
        arr = temp;
        *size = (*size)*2;
        *total_elements = *total_elements + 1;
        for(int i=0;i< *total_elements;i++){
            printf("%d\t",*(arr+i));
        }
    }
}

void pop()
{
}

void main()
{
    int select=0;
    int *arr, size=0, total_elements = 0;
    while(select!=4)
    {
        printf("\nSelect a number\n1. push\n2. pop\n3. display\n4. exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&select);
        switch (select)
        {
            case 1: 
                printf("Enter element to push: ");
                int ele;
                scanf("%d",&ele);
                push(arr,&size,ele,&total_elements);
                break;
            
            case 3: 
                display(arr, &total_elements);
                break;

            case 4: break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

After entering 3 elements(11,22,33).
The print output from the push function.

```
11      22      33
```

The print output from the display function.

```
11      22      -1943936495
```

I'm sure that there is a mistake in the push function while using pointers. Why is this causing?

Comment: If so allowed, compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug information), and use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Notice that your local variable `arr` is not initialized. I recommend initializing every pointer (e.g. to `NULL`). You may want to define a `grow` function returning a pointer and call `arr= grow(arr);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I'll add the grow function for better understanding

Comment: Use `realloc` instead of the homebrew growth code.

Comment: `*arr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));` is an error. If you don't see an error message then reconfigure your compiler settings. It is a complete and utter waste of time to try and run programs that have compile-time mistakes .

Comment: How is it an error? can you explain more?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yes I read about the realloc, it is an easy approach for growing array. Since I'm learning about pointers, I thought of using malloc/calloc approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

1. `arr` is the array pointer.
2. `size` is the current number of filled/used elements.
3. `total_elements` is the number of *allocated* elements.

You are overallocating the `arr` (using `total_elements`) which is good.

But, you are conflating use of `size` and `total_elements`. In `display`, you should use `size`.

Note that, in `main`, you are *not* initializing `arr` [to `NULL`]. For your code, this is okay because of the way `push` is implemented. But, it's generally good practice to set it to `NULL`--see below.

In `push`, you're *not* updating `arr` for the *caller*.

Also, `push` is more complicated than it needs to be (i.e.) too many special cases.

If `main` initialized `arr`, then `push` could just use `realloc` (as `realloc` handles a null pointer as doing a `malloc` [internally]).

Instead of passing 3 things to `push`, we can create a control `struct` for the array that contains your separate scalar values. This greatly simplifies the code. We just pass around the [single] `struct` pointer to all the functions.

---

Here is some refactored code. For testing purposes, I added a `case 5`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *arr;                           // pointer to array data
    int size;                           // number of filled/inuse elements
    int total_elements;                 // number of allocated elements
} dynarr_t;

void
display(dynarr_t *dyn)
{

    if (dyn->size == 0) {
        printf("No elements present in array\n");
        return;
    }

    int totlen = 0;

    for (int i = 0;  i < dyn->size;  i++) {
        if (totlen >= 68) {
            printf("\n");
            totlen = 0;
        }
        int curlen = printf(" %d",dyn->arr[i]);
        totlen += curlen;
    }

    if (totlen > 0)
        printf("\n");
}

void
push(dynarr_t *dyn,int ele)
{

    // grow the array
    if (dyn->size >= dyn->total_elements) {
        // the amount here is arbitrary
        dyn->total_elements += 10;

        dyn->arr = realloc(dyn->arr,sizeof(*dyn->arr) * dyn->total_elements);

        // out of memory
        if (dyn->arr == NULL) {
            perror("push");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // append new element
    dyn->arr[dyn->size++] = ele;
}

// RETURNS: 1=valid, 0=empty
int
pop(dynarr_t *dyn,int *ele)
{

    // no elements in array
    if (dyn->size <= 0)
        return 0;

    // pop the last element
    *ele = dyn->arr[--dyn->size];

    return 1;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int select = 0;
    int ele;

    // allocate a pointer to the array control struct
    dynarr_t *dyn = calloc(1,sizeof(*dyn));

    while (select != 4) {
        printf("\nSelect a number\n1. push\n2. pop\n3. display\n4. exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &select);
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter element to push: ");

            scanf("%d", &ele);
            push(dyn, ele);
            break;

        case 2:
            if (pop(dyn,&ele))
                printf("main: pop %d\n",ele);
            else
                printf("main: pop empty\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            display(dyn);
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        case 5:  // internal test
            for (int ele = 1;  ele <= 100;  ++ele)
                push(dyn,ele);
            display(dyn);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    // free up the memory
    free(dyn->arr);
    free(dyn);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the test output [for `5 4`]:

```
Select a number
1. push
2. pop
3. display
4. exit
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
 96 97 98 99 100

Select a number
1. push
2. pop
3. display
4. exit
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. I thought of doing it using structure, but then I changed my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `push` function works correctly because of `arr = temp;`. Observe that `arr` is actually a local variable inside the `push` function. When the `push` function returns, the `main` does *not* have any idea that the `arr` variable was ever changed in `push`.

When you pass `arr` to `display`, the copy that main has is sent. If you need to update `arr` inside another function (`push` in this case), you need to pass the address of `arr` - `push(&arr,&size,ele,&total_elements);` Likewise, the `push` function should now accept `int **arr` instead of `int *arr`. Also, make sure you dereference `arr` the right number of times inside `push`.

Inside `push`, you can update `arr` by doing `*arr = temp;`. After this, `arr` will point to the new array that was `malloc`ed in `push` and you can pass `arr` to your `display` function.

Comment: So, you have pointed out what the error is; how about also including a solution?

Comment: @babon when I add only 2 elements and print using the display function, I get the desired result.

Comment: @babon, you are correct about the `main does not have any idea that the arr was changed`. This happens only when I try to extend the array, the main has no idea about the update.